# How to get Video file summary in java

Tags: java

In windows, we can see the properties of the Video file such as Title , Subject , Author. I just want to get the Summary (Title , Subject , Author) in java coding. How to read these properties in java. I have searched but i didnt get clear. if any one know how to slove it. plz guide me. plz tell the which Jar to use and sample coding if possible.

Comment: Either do it yourself (you'll need to know at what byte which information is stored) or google for a library that does it for you: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&q=java+video+library&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&redir_esc=&ei=75jyS7b_C4mO_AbHi7CMDQ

Answer (score 0):

see Java Media Framework [JMF] : http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any particular library that does this, but of course you should be aware that there is no such thing as "a video file"; the choice of audio and video codecs as well as the container format will vary wildly between different video files, and hence what is supported.

However, I suspect that the [Java Media Framework](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/index.jsp) would be a good place to start.  This would also give you a better understanding of what files are supported, and the limitations of the technology.